# How to loop multiple decay rate in multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: loops, apache-spark, pyspark, lag, pow

I try to pass a list in parameter of my function.

My list is composed of different coefficients to be apply to lag numerous columns.

However, I only manage to generate the columns in my dataframe for the first value of my list.

this is my actual result :

"col1", "col2", "col1_0.2", "col2_0.2"

what is expected :

"col1", "col2", "col1_0.2", "col2_0.2", "col1_0.4", "col2_0.4", "col1_0.6", "col2_0.6"

I must have missed a few things in my loop ?

```
selected_col = col_selector(df, ["col1", "col2"])


w = Window.partitionBy("student").orderBy("date")
coef = (.1,.4,.6)

def custom_coef(col, w, coef):
    for x in coef:
        return sum(
            pow(i, x) * F.lag(F.col(col), i, default=0).over(w)
            for i in range(1)
        ).alias(col +"_"+str(x))

new_df = df.select(
    F.col("*"),
    *[custom_coef(col, w, coef) for col in selected_col]
)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement in the `custom_coef` function ends the function after the first execution of loop over `coef`. This means that `custom_coef` will always return the first column definition, and this is the column definition for coef 0.1. As the function is called once per column in `selected_col` you get the result that you are describing.

One way to fix the problem without changing the structure of the code is to replace `return` with `yield`. This way `custom_coef` creates one generator per element of `selected_col`. These generators can be chained with [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and this result can be used as parameter of the `select` statement:

```python
def custom_coef(col, w, coef):
    for x in coef:
        yield sum(  #use yield instead of return
            pow(i, x) * F.lag(F.col(col), i, default=0).over(w)
            for i in range(1)
        ).alias(col +"_"+str(x))

new_df = df.select(
    F.col("*"),
    *chain(*[custom_coef(col, w, coef) for col in selected_col]) #chain the generators
)
new_df.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code comment! I just had a great time learning about the generators. It's very exciting. I can think of tons of things I can automate now!